# If $x$ is irrational, can $x^2+x$ be rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a simple question, but I can't come up with a way to answer it. I'm quite a beginner at problems like these so I don't know how to proceed. The only thing I came up with was that square roots of prime numbers are example of numbers where this won't of course work, since we have a $\sqrt{p}$ and therefore the number would become

$$(\sqrt{p})^2+\sqrt{p} = p + \sqrt{p}$$

...which of course is irrational.

**If $x$ is irrational, can $x^2+x$ be rational?**

Comment: We had this question yesterday. Anyway, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917723/determine-the-irrational-numbers-x-such-that-both-x22x-and-x3-6x-are-ra) is a solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Pardon me, it's hard finding questions that solve the same typ of question but have another type of title. Excuse me once again.

Comment: Take the solutions of $x^2+x=\sqrt2$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example
$$x = \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2} \not \in \Bbb Q$$
but
$$x^2 +x = \frac{7}{4}\in \Bbb Q$$

PS: Let's denote $x = y -\frac{1}{2}$ then $x^2+x = y^2 - \frac{1}{4}$. The problem is equivalent to find $y \not \in \Bbb Q$ such that $ y^2 \in \Bbb Q$.
Hence, all solutions are $ x = \sqrt{y} - \frac{1}{2}$ where $y$ is *not square number of any rational number*.

Comment: Thanks, easy and simple!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you are looking for an irrational solution $x$ to the quadratic equation $x^2+x+a = 0$, where $a$ is rational.

Answer (score 2):

The “rational root theorem” tells us that if $a$ is an integer then any rational solution $x$ of
$$
 x^2 + x = a
$$
is an integer and divides $a$.

It follows immediately that – for example – the solutions of $x^2+x=1$ are irrational.